# ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Exit Code Block

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, razor, asp.net-webpages

Does anybody know how to exit a code block without interrupting page load in ASP.NET Web Page (Razor) in VB language? Let's say I have a login mechanism that execute in the following order:

Before page load:

1. Check if user id exist.
2. Check if password match.

if the user id does not exist, display error message then skip password validation and let the rest of the html page (body, footer) load. My current solution is to use VB specific GoTo.. statement which I think is ugly. Does anybody has a more elegant solution? Below is a simple sample code:

```
@Code
dim login As New clsLogin 'assume this class handles login validation
dim inputUserID As String 'this variable hold user id entered by user
dim inputPwd As String 'this is password entered by user

'First, check if that ID exist in database
if login.userExist(inputUserID) = false then
    @<p>User does not exist !</p>
    GoTo skip
End If

'If ID exist, check if password match
if login.checkPwd(inputUserID, inputPwd) = false then
    @<p>Password Mismatch !</p>
    GoTo skip
End If

'Passes all validation, display success message
@<p>Login Successful !</p>

skip:
End Code
```

I tried to replace the GoTo statement with return statement. However, it also stopped the page loading. I put the validation server code before any HTML is displayed and if I use return statement it wont show the HTML page. Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing `Controller` and `View`.

Comment: This is not MVC. It is ASP.NET web pages. It's just like PHP and Classic ASP.

Comment: Oh, no wonder I felt so dirty reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer could use a function:

```
@Functions


function Check(byval inputUserID as integer, byval inputPwd as string) as string
dim login As New clsLogin 'assume this class handles login validation
dim result as string = string.Empty

'First, check if that ID exist in database
if login.userExist(inputUserID) = false then
    return "User does not exist !"

End If


'If ID exist, check if password match
if login.checkPwd(inputUserID, inputPwd) = false then
    return "Password Mismatch !"
End If

return result

end function
End functions

@Code

dim inputUserID As String 'this variable hold user id entered by user
dim inputPwd As String 'this is password entered by user

dim msg = @Check(inputUserID,inputPwd)
'Passes all validation, display success message
if string.isnullorempty(msg) then
    msg = "<p>Login Successful !</p>"

end if
@msg
End Code
```

Hoever reading your comment seems you are looking for an elegant and sustainable solution, so I think you could approach your problem with a loosely coupled `ValidationManager`:

---

**VB** (translated with [Telerik code converted](http://converter.telerik.com/))

---

```
Public Interface ILoginProvider
    Function UserExist(inputUserID As Integer) As Boolean
    Function CheckPwd(inputUserID As Integer, inputPwd As String) As Boolean
End Interface

Public Class LoginProvider
    Implements ILoginProvider
    Public Function UserExist(inputUserID As Integer) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
    Public Function CheckPwd(inputUserID As Integer, inputPwd As String) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function
End Class

Public Class ValidationResult
    Public Property Result() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_Result
        End Get
        Set
            m_Result = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Result As Boolean
    Public Property ResultMessage() As String
        Get
            Return m_ResultMessage
        End Get
        Set
            m_ResultMessage = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ResultMessage As String
End Class

Public MustInherit Class Validator
    Protected _provider As ILoginProvider
    Protected _inputUserID As Integer
    Protected _inputPwd As String

    Public Sub New(provider As ILoginProvider, inputUserID As Integer, inputPwd As String)
        _provider = provider
        _inputPwd = inputPwd

        _inputUserID = inputUserID
    End Sub
    Public MustOverride Function Validate() As ValidationResult
End Class

Public Class UserExistenceValidator
    Inherits Validator
    Public Sub New(provider As LoginProvider, inputUserID As Integer, inputPwd As String)

        MyBase.New(provider, inputUserID, inputPwd)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function Validate() As ValidationResult
        Dim result = New ValidationResult()
        Dim check = _provider.UserExist(_inputUserID)
        result.Result = check
        If Not check Then
            result.ResultMessage = "User Doesn't exist"
        End If

        Return result
    End Function
End Class

Public Class UserPasswordValidator
    Inherits Validator
    Public Sub New(provider As LoginProvider, inputUserID As Integer, inputPwd As String)

        MyBase.New(provider, inputUserID, inputPwd)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function Validate() As ValidationResult
        Dim result = New ValidationResult()
        Dim check = _provider.CheckPwd(_inputUserID, _inputPwd)
        result.Result = check
        If Not check Then
            result.ResultMessage = "Wrong Password"
        End If

        Return result
    End Function
End Class

Public Class ValidationManager
    Private _validators As List(Of Validator)
    Public Sub New()
        _validators = New List(Of Validator)()
    End Sub

    Public Function Validate() As ValidationResult
        Dim result As ValidationResult = Nothing
        For Each item As var In _validators
            result = item.Validate()
            If Not result.Result Then
                Return result
            End If
        Next

        Return New ValidationResult() With { _
            Key .Result = True, _
            Key .ResultMessage = "Successfull validated" _
        }
    End Function
End Class
```

---

**C#**

---

```
  public interface ILoginProvider
  {
    bool UserExist(int inputUserID);
    bool CheckPwd(int inputUserID, string inputPwd);
  }

  public class LoginProvider: ILoginProvider
  {
    public bool UserExist(int inputUserID)
    {
      return true;
    }
    public bool CheckPwd(int inputUserID, string inputPwd)
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  public class ValidationResult
  {
    public bool Result { get; set; }
    public string ResultMessage { get; set; }
  }

  public abstract class Validator
  {
    protected ILoginProvider _provider;
    protected int _inputUserID; 
    protected string _inputPwd;

    public Validator(ILoginProvider provider, int inputUserID, string inputPwd)
    {
      _provider = provider;
      _inputPwd = inputPwd;
      _inputUserID = inputUserID;

    }
    public abstract ValidationResult Validate();
  }

  public class UserExistenceValidator : Validator
  {
    public UserExistenceValidator(LoginProvider provider,int inputUserID, string inputPwd): base(provider,inputUserID, inputPwd)
    {

    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate()
    {
      var result = new ValidationResult();
      var check = _provider.UserExist(_inputUserID); 
      result.Result = check;
      if(!check)
        result.ResultMessage = "User Doesn't exist";

      return result;
    }
  }

  public class UserPasswordValidator : Validator
  {
    public UserPasswordValidator(LoginProvider provider, int inputUserID, string inputPwd)
      : base(provider, inputUserID, inputPwd)
    {

    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate()
    {
      var result = new ValidationResult();
      var check = _provider.CheckPwd(_inputUserID, _inputPwd);
      result.Result = check;
      if (!check)
        result.ResultMessage = "Wrong Password";

      return result;
    }
  }

  public class ValidationManager
  {
    List<Validator> _validators;
    public ValidationManager()
    {
      _validators = new List<Validator>();
    }

    public ValidationResult Validate()
    {
      ValidationResult result = null;
      foreach (var item in _validators)
      {
        result = item.Validate();
        if(!result.Result)
          return result;
      }

      return new ValidationResult(){Result = true,ResultMessage="Successfull validated" };
    }
  }
```

---

**Use**

---

```
@Function Check() As string

  Dim login As New clsLogin 'assume this class handles login validation
  Dim inputUserID As String 'this variable hold user id entered by user
  Dim inputPwd As String 'this is password entered by user


  Dim login As New LoginProvider()
  Dim validators = New List(Of Validator)()
  validators.Add(New UserExistenceValidator(login, 1, "test1"))
  validators.Add(New UserPasswordValidator(login, 1, "test1"))

  Dim manager = New ValidationManager(validators)
  Dim result = manager.Validate()
  return string.format("<p>{0}</p>",result.ResultMessage)


 End Function


  @Code

    @Check()

  End Code
```

Comment: I've thought of doing that. Using result to indicate which error occurred. However, if I have more validations say like10 more different validation. I would have to put the: if string.isnullorempty(result) 9 times following the next validation. If result is not empty on first validation, the next if string.isnullorempty statement still gets executed 9 more time which I think it is still not an elegant solution.

Comment: @AlbertTobing edited with return statement to avoid null or empty check, you can do your checks inside the function and test null or empty only in one place

Comment: I found the solution ! Thx partially to your info on how to put function inside webpage.

Comment: @AlbertTobing could you add your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Thx to InvernoMuto to show me how to define functions inside webpage.

First I created a class to hold login result that can provide reason if login fails.

```
Class LoginResult
    Public Property LoginSuccess As Boolean
    Public Property Reason As String
End Class
```

Then I created the following function for login validations

```
@Functions
    Function CheckLogin(User As String, Pwd as String) As LoginResult
        dim login As New clsLogin
        Dim res as New LoginResult

        res.LoginSuccess = True

        if login.userExist(inputUserID) = false then
            res.LoginSuccess = False
            res.Reason = "User does not exist !"
            return res
        end if

        if login.checkPwd(inputUserID, inputPwd) = false then
            res.LoginSuccess = False
            res.Reason = "Password mismatch !"
            return res
        end if

        return res
    End Function
End Functions
```

Then on the Login HTML page I just call the following code:

```
dim lr as LoginResult
lr = CheckLogin("someone", "password")

if lr.LoginSuccess = True then
    @<p>Login Success !</p>
else
    @<p>Error: @lr.Reason</p>
end if
```